# Can you receive Ayin Hara from a gentile?

Tags: gentiles, ayin-hara-evil-eye

There's a concept in Judaism called Ayin Hara (The Evil Eye) - when others see your accomplishments and speak about them you put yourself in danger of receiving divine punishment or strict judgement.

Can Ayin Hara only be triggered by a Jew or can Gentiles equally cause Ayin Hara.

Comment: [According to R Herschel Schachter](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/772117/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Segulas,_Superstition,_and_the_Ayin_Hara), ayin hara works as a sort of prayer: do gentiles have the power of prayer?

Comment: Was Sarah imeinu a Jewess according to you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Gentile **can** give *ayin hara*, as explained in [this article](http://www.yeshivahcollege.com/Yeshivah_College___hmkllh_hysybh/PARSHA/Entries/2012/7/6_The_Evil_Eye__Superstition_or_Reality.html) :

> The Mishna in Avot[3] spells out the three negative traits that Balaam
>   embodied:
>
> "Whoever possesses the following three traits is of the disciples of
>   our father Abraham; and whoever possesses the opposite three traits is
>   of the disciples of the wicked Balaam... The disciples of the wicked
>   Balaam have an evil eye, a haughty spirit and a greedy soul."
>
> On the third occasion when Balaam tried to curse the Jews, it says,
>   "Balaam raised his eyes and saw Israel dwelling according to its
>   tribes."[10] Rashi explains that he attempted to cast an evil eye on
>   them. Thus we learn that Balaam had an evil eye.

Comment: I'm not convinced; in the context of that mishna, I think that ayin hara may mean something else.

Comment: @Shokhet - I'm game. Please elaborate on what other explanation may work, here.